# Docker does not run python script

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a problem. I want to run a python script in a docker container. Unfortunately `python script.py` is not being executed when building my container. When I go inside my docker container and execute my `python script.py` via command line, it works.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.4-alpine3.14
WORKDIR ./
ADD auth ./auth
ADD .devcontainer ./.devcontainer
COPY script.py .
COPY .env .
COPY publish_random.py .
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
CMD python script.py
```

Console output:

[image: output]

Comment: Since you haven't specified the command you run I suggest you read about the [difference between the CMD and ENTRYPOINT](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint/#:~:text=CMD%20vs%20ENTRYPOINT%3A%20Fundamental%20differences&text=CMD%20commands%20are%20ignored%20by,as%20arguments%20of%20the%20command.)

Comment: @Max even if I change it to `ENTRYOPINT`, it is still not being executed

Comment: From your message ("not being executed when building my container") and the console output, the behaviour is expected. The script `script.py` will only run when you **run** a container based on the image you're building. It will not run the script when you **build** the image. See [CMD documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for reference.

Comment: @MarcosParreiras thank you a lot! After building the container I did `docker compose up -d` and ran `docker compose run <name of the container>` and the expected output is shown in the console!